# Is it possible to disable a button column in an ObjectListView by row?

Tags: objectlistview

In an ObjectListView you can make a column a button column by setting the IsButton property to true.

Is it possible to enable/disable the button based on data in the row?

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes.

The docs state

> If the aspect for a cell is null or empty, no button will be drawn. Use this to produce rows without buttons.

So you can probably just use an AspectGetter that checks the data of the model object from the current row and returns NULL depending on the value.